# For which sets $U,V\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is $g(x,y)=( e^{5y} , x+y ) $ a bijection, calculate inverse function $g^{-1}$ for those sets

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

$g^*:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} , (x,y)\mapsto ( e^{5y}\, ,\, x+y  ) $
with the components $g_1(x,y)=e^{5y}$ and $g_2(x,y)=x+y$.

$(i)$
Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $a\leq 0$. For every $y\in\mathbb{R}$ $(a,b)\neq g(x,y)$ because $g_1(x,y)=e^{5y}> 0$.

Now let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $a>0$ be arbitrary, then there exist $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ with  $(a,b)= ( e^{5y}\, ,\, x+y  )$ because $\exp:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is bijective.

Statement:

$g:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} , (x,y)\mapsto ( e^{5y}\, ,\, x+y ) $ is a bijection.

Proof:

With $(i)$ follows the surjectivity of $g$. Assuming $g(x,y)=g(a,b)$ for $(x,y),(a,b)\in\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$:

$( g_1(x,y)\, ,\, g_2(x,y) )= ( g_1(a,b)\, ,\, g_2(a,b) )\Leftrightarrow (g_1(x,y)- g_1(a,b)\, ,\, g_2(x,y)-g_2(a,b))=(0,0)$

$\Rightarrow g_1(x,y)- g_1(a,b)=e^{5y}-e^{5b}=0\Rightarrow y=b$ becaus $\exp$ is a bijection.

$g_2(x,y)-g_2(a,b))=x+y-(a+b)=x+b-(a+b)=x-a=0 \Rightarrow x=a$

So $g(x,y)=g(a,b)\Rightarrow (x,y)=(a,b)$ i.e. $g$ is injective.

q.e.d.

Statement:

$g^{-1}:\mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0} , (u,v)\mapsto ( v-\frac15 \ln u\, ,\,\frac15 \ln u  ) $
is the inverse function of $g$

Proof:

Let $u=g_1(x,y)$ and $v=g_2(x,y)$.

$g^{-1}(g(x,y))=g^{-1}(u,v)=g^{-1}(e^{5y}, \, x+y)=( x+y-\frac15 \ln e^{5y}\, ,\,  \frac15 \ln e^{5y})=(x+y-y,y)=(x,y)$

and

$g(g^{-1}(u,v))=g( v-\frac15 \ln u\, ,\,\frac15 \ln u  )=(e^{5\cdot \frac15 \ln u}\, , v-\frac15 \ln u+\frac15 \ln u)=(u,v)  $

q.e.d.

Are the proofs correct?

Comment: They are correct.